# Is there a better way to use middleware in middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

For example I want to create some middleware that uses Passport but I don't want to have to require Passport in my app(s) that use this custom middleware. I believe I can do the following to achieve this. Is this proper? Is there a better way to do this?

**someModule.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    passport = require('passport');

exports.someMiddleware = function(app) {
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  return function(req, res, next) {
    // Do something
    next();
  }
}
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');

var someModule = require('./someModule');

app = express();

app.use(someModule.someMiddleware(app))
```

rather than......

**someModule.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    passport = require('passport');

exports.someMiddleware = function(app) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    // Do something
    next();
  }
}
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    passport = require('passport');

var someModule = require('./someModule');

app = express();

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(someModule.someMiddleware())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using embedded apps to keep code well organized and reusable.  Keep routes in the embedded app as short as possible, so that the main app that is using them can set an appropriate base path.

*module.js*

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');

var controller = module.exports = express();
controller.use(passport.initialize());
controller.use(passport.session());
// Login
controller.post('/', function (request, response, next) { /* ... */ });
// Logout
controller.del('/', function (request, response, next) { /* ... */ });
```

*app.js*

```
var app = express();
var controller = require('./controllers/module');

app.use('/authentication', controller);
```

Comment: Thank you. This got me in the right direction. Here are a few more resources I found helpful. https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose/wiki#wiki-controllers  and   
http://timstermatic.github.io/blog/2013/08/17/a-simple-mvc-framework-with-node-and-express/